# StreamReader output

Tags: c#, output, streamreader

In C# why output of this 2 code is different from each other  ?

```
StreamReader test = new StreamReader(@"C:\a.txt");

while (test.ReadLine() != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(test.ReadLine());
}
```

And this code :

```
StreamReader test = new StreamReader(@"C:\a.txt");

string line = "";

while ((line = test.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Comment: Please add a output in the code

Comment: @Smit, why do you need output?

Comment: as it's mention in the Question @Qwertiy

Answer (score 12):

Each time you call `test.ReadLine()` you read one new line, so the first code skippes a half of them.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, use this code instead:

```
while(!test.EndOfStream)
{
   Console.WriteLine(test.ReadLine());
}
```

Comment: Is there any difference of your version with second code related to trailing linebreak? Not sure about C#, but in C++ it's not recommended to check for EOF in such way.

Comment: Why i should use this ?

Comment: Sorry, I figured you tried to read the file from beginning to end. If you need to skip every second line, your first solution works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Both the code works same with little magic ,becuase of the reason:

**test.ReadLine():**
**return:** The next line from the input stream, or null if the end of the input stream is reached.

```
      // So,Let's say your a.txt contain the following cases:
       case 1:"Hello World"
       while (test.ReadLine() != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("HI" + test.ReadLine());
        }

   // since,we have only one line ,so next line is null and finally it reached the EOD.

    case 2:"Hello World"
   "I am a coder"
       while (test.ReadLine() != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("HI" + test.ReadLine());
        }

  // since,we have  two line so ,next line is "I am a coder".
 //It returns:Hi I am a coder.


// And in the below code we are reading and assigning to string variable

        StreamReader test1 = new StreamReader(@"D:\a.txt");

        string line = "";

        while ((line = test1.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
```

Comment: Format your answer, please.